# Angular Gridster store position in DB

Tags: angularjs, database, gridster

I am building a customized Angular Gridster Dashboard. On loading the page, I call a function that loads the position, size and content of the Gridster Widgets from a database

```
    function getDashboard() {
        $scope.dashboard.widgets = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.filtered_activities, function(object) {
            $scope.dashboard.widgets.push(
                {
                    pk: object.pk,
                    process: object.process,
                    row: object.row,
                    col: object.col,                    
                    sizeY: object.sizeY,
                    sizeX: object.sizeX,
                }
            )           
        });
    };
```

This works fine, and the widgets are just as I left them before I reloaded the page and the putActivies(widget) stores them in the DB.

However, when I want to drag them to a different position, I only get the position that I stored in the database and not the current position.

```
    $scope.gridsterOptions = {
        margins: [20, 20],
        outerMargin: false,
        pushing: true,
        columns: 6,
        rowHeight: 100,
        draggable: {
            handle: 'h2',
            enabled: true,
            stop: function(event, $element, widget) {
                console.log(widget.col);
                putActivities(widget);
            }
        },
        resizable: {
        enabled: false,
    }
    };
```

So the console.log(widget.col) only gives me the database position, not the current one.
When I leave out the row and the col property from the getDashboard() it works, but then of course the don't have the right position.

Is there another way to access the widgets.col (and row) attribute) ?

My html looks like this:
 li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets"

Answer (score 2):

`draggable: {
            handle: 'h2',
            enabled: true,
            stop: function(event, $element, widget) {
                console.log($element)
                putActivities($element);
            }
        },`

This would do your job. 
Note: $element is an object which has sixeX, sizeY, col,row which store current position(col,row) and size(sizeX,sizeY)